# conditionally use another value from secondary table otherwise use first table values

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a quick way/means to use a discounted price from a secondary table if indeed there is a discount on the said productiD otherwise I want to use the first table price.

The portion I have marked with the #########'s is where I'm stuck at.... What do I do?

Currently what I have is this:

```
SELECT
 cat.`CategoryId` AS CategoryId
 ,prod.`ProductId` AS ProductId
 ,COUNT(prod.`ProductId`)AS product_count
 ,prod.`Price` AS price
 ,adj.`ProductPrice` AS Adj_Price

 FROM ax_category cat
 INNER JOIN xx_products prod USING(categoryid)
 INNER JOIN xx_subcategory sc ON(prod.Subcategoryid = sc.SubCategoryId)
 INNER JOIN xx_services s USING(productid)
 LEFT JOIN xx_invoiceline il USING(serviceid)
 LEFT JOIN xx_invoices i USING(invoiceid)
 #LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND s.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
 LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND s.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.DateEnd,'%Y-%m') = '2013-11'

############################################
IF EXISTS(
SELECT a.`ProductPrice` AS price 
FROM xx_adjustments AS a
WHERE a.`ProductId` = '999'
#limit 1
)
############################################


GROUP BY prod.`ProductId`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT
cat.`CategoryId` AS CategoryId
,prod.`ProductId` AS ProductId
,COUNT(prod.`ProductId`)AS product_count
,prod.`Price` AS price
,adj.`ProductPrice` AS Adj_Price
,COALESCE(adj.`ProductPrice`, prod.`Price`) AS discountedPrice
FROM ax_category cat
INNER JOIN xx_products prod USING(categoryid)
INNER JOIN xx_subcategory sc ON(prod.Subcategoryid = sc.SubCategoryId)
INNER JOIN xx_services s USING(productid)
LEFT JOIN xx_invoiceline il USING(serviceid)
LEFT JOIN xx_invoices i USING(invoiceid)
#LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND s.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND s.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.DateEnd,'%Y-%m') = '2013-11'
GROUP BY prod.`ProductId`
```

See a simple example [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4668a/1).

Comment: Glad to know that you got it sorted @user2917229. GOD bless and Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

How about this (see discountedPrice column in select clause):

```
SELECT
 cat.`CategoryId` AS CategoryId
 ,prod.`ProductId` AS ProductId
 ,COUNT(prod.`ProductId`)AS product_count
 ,prod.`Price` AS price
 ,adj.`ProductPrice` AS Adj_Price
 ,IFNULL(adj.`ProductPrice`, prod.`Price`) AS discountedPrice

 FROM ax_category cat
 INNER JOIN xx_products prod USING(categoryid)
 INNER JOIN xx_subcategory sc ON(prod.Subcategoryid = sc.SubCategoryId)
 INNER JOIN xx_services s USING(productid)
 LEFT JOIN xx_invoiceline il USING(serviceid)
 LEFT JOIN xx_invoices i USING(invoiceid)
 #LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND s.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
 LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (prod.`ProductId` = adj.`ProductId` AND prod.`Quantity` = adj.`Quantity`)
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.DateEnd,'%Y-%m') = '2013-11'

GROUP BY prod.`ProductId`
```

if there is no product price in xx_adjustment for particular productId, use price from xx_products.Price.

Comment: are you sure with this line `LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (s.ProductId = adj.ProductId AND s.Quantity = adj.Quantity)`. Shouldnt it be like: `LEFT JOIN xx_adjustments adj ON (prod.ProductId = adj.ProductId AND prod.Quantity = adj.Quantity)`?

Comment: hi @user2917229, just updated my answer. How is the result if you run my query again?

Comment: and what value returned for the Adj_Price, is it null?